# C++ Program returns no values for text and string data in file

Tags: c++, file-io

I am trying to write a C++ program that reads an input file titled employee.txt and computes and displays a payroll schedule. The intended output should list a social security number, name, and gross pay for the individuals in the file. My input file looks like this:

[input file](https://i.stack.imgur.com/t1xMy.png)

The values above (left to right) are name, social security number, payment rate per hour, and total number of hours. The final output should look like this:

[intended output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qGDVA.png)

In this case, the gross pay is being calculated from multiplying rate and hours together. My output however does not look like this because I am not receiving some values. My received output looks as follows:

[my output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cYNGZ.png)

I have copied my code below. I dont know what I am missing in order to read the values for the file. If anyone could help it would be greatly appreciated! Thanks!

---

```
#include <iostream>

#include <fstream> //needed for ifstream and ofstream

#include <cstdlib> //needed for exit()

#include <string>

#include <iomanip>

using namespace std;

int main()

{

       string filename = "employee.txt";

       ofstream outputFile;

       ifstream inFile;

       int numEmployees;

       int socialSecurity = 0;

       string name;

       double grossPay = 0, hours = 0, rate = 0;



      //determine number of employees

      cout << "How many employees do you have? ";

      cin >> numEmployees;



   inFile.open(filename.c_str()); //create and open file

   if (outputFile.fail())

   {

         cout << "The file was not successfully opened" << endl;

         exit(1);

   }


   inFile.open("employee.txt");

   cout << "Reading data from file.\n\n";



   cout << "Social \nSecurity \nNumber \t\t Name \t\t Gross Pay\n";

   cout << "-------- \t ----- \t\t ----------\n";

   for (int count = 1; count <= numEmployees; count++)

   {

         inFile >> name; //Receive employee name

         inFile >> socialSecurity; // receive employee SS num

         cout << socialSecurity << "\t"; // display SS num

         cout << name << "\t"; // display employee name

         inFile >> rate; // receive employee rate

         inFile >> hours; // receive total hours

         grossPay = hours * rate; // calculate gross pay

         cout << grossPay << endl; // display gross pay

   }



   inFile.close();

   system("pause");

   return 0;

}
```

Comment: This might not be related to the problems you're having, but I notice that you call `inFile.open(filename.c_str());` (where `.c_str()` is unneccessary, by the way), then you check `outputFile` instead of `inFile`, then you make a redundant call `inFile.open("employee.txt")`, on a file which has already been opened

Answer (score 0):

```
if (outputFile.fail())
```

should probably be

```
if (inFile.fail())
```

You may progress from there by specifying the absolute path of the input file.

Also, you call `open()` on the input file twice.

Answer (score 0):

I think you get this output if you don't have the example file in the correct directory and since you don't check the inFile fails to load, you won't get an error. You could easily check this with using an absolute path to your file.